# C#: Converting String to Sequence of Known Operations

Tags: c#, string, parsing, lexer

I want to convert a string of playing cards given as in A into a form B such that I can produce a result C.

```
A: "(AK,AQ,(A2:*h*h)):*s*s!AsQs,(JJ:*s*h)"
B: (((AsKs union AsQs union (A2 intersect hand with two hearts)) intersect hand with two spades) less AsQs) union (JJ intersect hand with one spade one heart)
C: AsKs,JsJh
```

The precedence of operations is

- 1) parentheses, '()'
- 2) intersect and less (left associative), ':!'
- 3) union, ','

I have the functionality to perform the operations in B, for example Intersect("AA", "*s*s") == "AsAs", but I need a way to get from the form A into the form B of inputs and associated operations that I can perform in sequence to arrive at C.

I have looked at [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/releases/view/8499) and some other lexer/parser solutions, but they seem a bit overkill for this problem. Is there a simpler solution?

- Perhaps recursively splitting the string into a tree with nodes representing operations?
- Breaking down the string in reverse order of precedence and pushing it onto a stack? If so how (roughly) could this be implemented?

A working example of what I am trying to emulate is given [here](http://www.propokertools.com/simulations). You can find a more detailed description of the syntax for A [here](http://www.propokertools.com/simulations/generic_syntax).

Comment: Can you provide a spec of syntax that A conforms to and how it is translated to B, exactly?

Comment: I wrote a Lexical Analyzer a while back called TokenIcer that might just be exactly what you need for your project. Check the [project out here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/220042/Easily-Create-Your-Own-Parser). It will create code for you in any .NET language you wish! You simply define your rules as RegEx expressions and it creates source code for you automatically for the complete Lexical Analyzer. In addition, I wrote a Math Parser, which uses TokenIcer. With this, you can see how to parse expressions. Check it out [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274093/Math-Parser-NET)

Comment: @Superbest The syntax can be found here http://www.propokertools.com/simulations/generic_syntax

Comment: So why don't you use Irony? I haven't done much of this sort of thing but it sounds like they've solve a lot of the problem for you already, and all you need to do is plug in your set operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse `A` to construct a tree of instructions and then execute them starting from the leaves (as I assume you'd want to execute the contents of the innermost brackets first). For this parsing task, you could use Regexes, or whatever else you want. Off the top of my head, I think you can first look for the parenthesis and operator symbols to figure out the tree structure, then fill in each leaf with the actual elementary instruction and each junction with the operator.

The data structure storing `A` can be composed of objects (call them `Expression`) implementing an interface `IOperand`; each `Expression` should have three fields:

1. A field `Operator` which is an instance of `enum Operations {Union, Intersection, SetDiff}`, or just a string, depending on which you prefer.
2. Two fields `Operand1` and `Operand2`, which can be either something like "Ah" (defining a set of cards), or another `Expression`. Therefore, they should be declared as instances of `IOperand`.

Your class for holding a single set of cards, like "Ah", should also implement this `IOperand`. The interface `IOperand` itself need not actually do anything.

For matching each given instruction to an operation, you could use a simple switch, or alternatively a `Dictionary` of `string` (or `enum`) to `delegate IOperand SetOp(IOperand, IOperand);`, and then populate your `Dictionary` with (anonymous) functions (that would contain the instructions for `B`).

In the `Dictionary` case, you would simply be able to do `instructionList[thisExpression.Operation](thisExpression);` (this can probably be done a bit more elegantly to avoid referencing `thisExpression` twice) and the appropriate C# translation of the string input would be executed.

**Proof of Concept**

I have made a basic implementation and a console app to demonstrate usage here: https://bitbucket.org/Superbest/lexer

If you succeed at progressing through the whole exercise with your sanity intact (the computer will use you as a surrogate parsing  and operation library, so good luck with that) then the final step should ask you to evaluate an expression equal to `C` and then print what you just entered back at you. (When running for the first time, you might want to comply with the program's directives. I suspect it is very easy to break the code and get lots of exceptions, and confuse yourself very much if you try to think about what happened to your invalid input.)

If you are running the code as is, try the following sequence of answers (, = Enter):

```
n, y, 2, n, n, n, y, 2, n, n, y, n, y, 2, n, n, n, n, alpha, beta, gamma
```

Your output will be:

```
gamma
```

You should be able to simply update the bodies of methods marked obsolete and have a working program.

If you wish to add more binary operations, see the TODO in the body of `Simplification.Simplification()`. The appropriate syntax will be obvious from looking at the three operations I already made; as it is, the code supports only binary operations. If your methods consume strings, you can use the `SimplifiedOperand.Symbol` field.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this as a solution (using the tree idea from Superbest's answer). Any comments on things you would change would be appreciated!

- Input: "AsQs,(JJ!ss:xy),(AA:xy!ss)"
- Pretty Print Output: AsQs union (((JJ less ss) intersection xy) union ((AA intersection xy) less ss))

```
public class Node

{
    private string mStr;
    private string mOperation;
    private List mChildren = new List();
    //private Collection mCollection = new Collection();

    public Node(string input)
    {
        mStr = Regex.Replace(input, @"^\(([^\(\)]*)\)$", "$1");

        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        Split(mStr);

        return;
    }

    public Collection GenerateHands()
    {
        Collection collection = new Collection();

        if (Children == 0) { collection.Add(mStr); }

        if (Children > 0)
        {
            if (mOperation == "union") { collection = mChildren.ElementAt(0).GenerateHands().Union(mChildren.ElementAt(1).GenerateHands()); }
            if (mOperation == "intersect") { collection = mChildren.ElementAt(0).GenerateHands().Intersect(mChildren.ElementAt(1).GenerateHands()); }
            if (mOperation == "less") { collection = mChildren.ElementAt(0).GenerateHands().Less(mChildren.ElementAt(1).GenerateHands()); }
        }

        return collection;
    }

    public string PrettyPrint()
    {
        string print = "";

        if (Children == 0) { print += mStr; }

        if (Children > 0)
        {
            if (mChildren.ElementAt(0).Children > 0) { print += "("; }
            print += mChildren.ElementAt(0).PrettyPrint();
            if (mChildren.ElementAt(0).Children > 0) { print += ")"; }
            if (Children > 0) { print += " " + mOperation + " "; }
            if (mChildren.ElementAt(1).Children > 0) { print += "("; }
            print += mChildren.ElementAt(1).PrettyPrint();
            if (mChildren.ElementAt(1).Children > 0) { print += ")"; }
        }

        return print;
    }

    private void Split(string s)
    {
        // WARNING: Either could pass a,aa or a:aa

        // WARNING: This can hand down a 0 length string if ',' is at beginning or end of s.
        if (CommaOutsideBrackets(s) >= 0)
        {
            mChildren.Add(new Node(s.Substring(0, CommaOutsideBrackets(s))));
            mChildren.Add(new Node(s.Substring(CommaOutsideBrackets(s) + 1, s.Count() - CommaOutsideBrackets(s) - 1)));

            mOperation = "union";
        }

        // WARNING: This could throw negative if for example (aaaa)bb
        else if (OperatorOutsideBrackets(s) >= 0)
        {
            mChildren.Add(new Node(s.Substring(0, OperatorOutsideBrackets(s))));
            mChildren.Add(new Node(s.Substring(OperatorOutsideBrackets(s) + 1, s.Count() - OperatorOutsideBrackets(s) - 1)));

            if (s[OperatorOutsideBrackets(s)] == '!') { mOperation = "less"; }
            if (s[OperatorOutsideBrackets(s)] == ':') { mOperation = "intersection"; }
        }

        // We must be done?
        else
        {
        }
    }

    private int CommaOutsideBrackets(string s)
    {
        int countRound = 0, countSquare = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i = 0; i--)
        {
            if (s[i] == '!' || s[i] == ':') { return i; }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public string Str
    {
        get { return mStr; }
    }

    public int Children
    {
        get { return mChildren.Count; }
    }
}
```